# SocketTimeoutException in EJB client call

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss-4.2.x

I'm getting the reference to a remote EJB instance without any kind of problem but, sometimes, when I invoke one of its methods a *"java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"* is thrown from the client side. There seem to be no problems at the server side

Is there a way to set EJB client timeout on a per-invocation basis?

I'm using a pretty old JBoss version (4.2.1 GA)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. You can configure `InvokerLocater` attribute for Connector MBean.

   `<attribute name="InvokerLocator">socket://{jboss.bind.address}:3873/?socketTimeout=60000</attribute>`
2. Can provide more finer details for the config element under Configuration attribute. By default it's one minute.

   `<attribute name="socketTimeout">60000</attribute>`
3. Providing timeout parameters in the JNDI properties file.

   > **jnp.timeout :** The connection timeout in milliseconds. The default
   >   value is 0 which means the connection will block until the VM TCP/IP
   >   layer times out.
   >
   > **jnp.sotimeout :** The connected socket read timeout in milliseconds. The
   >   default value is 0 which means reads will block. This is the value
   >   passed to the Socket.setSoTimeout on the newly connected socket.

   To manually configure timeout for individual invocations, you have to create initial context with appropriate property values.